# how to define a class variable referring to an object of same class in python

Tags: java, python, class, static

Below is java code. I need to know the equivalent code in python:

```
class A {
    public static A obj = new A();
}
```

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935346/can-a-class-variable-be-an-instance-of-the-class

Comment: @PravatPanda -- Probably because OP is trying to reproduce that java construct in python.  Presumably, the people who would understand this question best also know java...

Comment: @mgilson sorry I didn't understood the question in first place.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this inside a python class definition, since the class has not yet been defined until the end of the `class:` block. You will have to set it after:

```
class A(object): 
    pass    
A.obj = A()
```

Comment: Note that you wouldn't normally do this in Python. The reason for doing it in Java is that you import classes, not files, so it makes sense to keep the "default" instance of a class as a static member of that class itself. In Python, you import modules, and instances can exist outside classes, so it makes sense to make the default instance of a class a module-level variable of the module where the class is defined.

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with a metaclass:

```
class SelfReferencingObjectMetaclass(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        attrs['obj'] = property(lambda self: self.__class__.obj)
        return super(SelfReferencingObjectMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

    @property
    def obj(cls):

        try:
            return cls._obj
        except AttributeError:
            cls._obj = cls()
            return cls._obj

class A(object):

    __metaclass__ = SelfReferencingObjectMetaclass
```

As @Daniel Roseman notes in the comments to @jamylak's answer though, there's probably an easier, more Pythonic way to solve the problem you have than this.  Following that comment, how you would accomplish this functionally, if not identically in terms of the object structure, would be by having a module like this:

`a.py`

```
class A(object):

    @property
    def obj(self):

        return a_inst


a_inst = A()
```

This does create the somewhat ugly construct `from a import A` in code that utilizes it, but it's a less complicated way to implement it.

Comment: I actually thought about posting this one too -- mostly because I've just starting learning about meta classes and was like "Hey, I could solve this one with a metaclass!"

Comment: metaclasses are a really great tool for certain things.  They are a bit alluringly dangerous to overuse though.  In this case, I like them better than either `cls.obj = cls()` or the `property` thing I have in my answer, just because I really hate the redundancy of the `from a import A` construct.  Though more often, you can avoid both problems by adjusting your implementation and pushing the class a level or 2 up your hierarchy.

Comment: I think @DanielRoseman meant that your second code would be `class A(object): pass` in module `a` and `obj` would be `a.obj` otherwise I don't see any advantage over `@property` to my code

Comment: There isn't one, really, just an alternative that could arguably be more useful in a non-toy example.  Also, it is arguably more "safe" and static-like, which could be seen as an advantage in this case, since `a_inst` could be seen as an implementation detail of the class, and `A.obj` is unassignable.  Of course, it does have the downside that it's not accessible from the class, but you could fix that with a descriptor, or a metaclass of course.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need this class member before any instance of the class is created? In not, you can try assigning it when the first instance is created:

```
class A (object):
    obj = None

    def __init__(self):
        if A.obj is None:
            a.obj = A()
            # or:
            a.obj = self
```

Comment: Or do it earlier, in `__new__`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd like to do that because you're trying to implement a pattern like singleton or something like that.

You may read the following recipe from activestate: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52558/

It explains the way it works and also shows some code.